# Why is my Javascript not working? but works with Chrome console

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to extract the values of my form inputs in a Javascript object but the value isn't being returned in console.log, it doesn't return the text. However, when I define the exact code ("var sub") in Chrome console it works fine and returns the value.

[image]

--------------------HTML-----------------------

```
<div id="form2">
    <form action="">
       <h2>Where are you moving to?</h2>
           <label for="">Collection</label>
           <input id="lol" type="text">
           <label for="">Delivery</label>
           <input type="text">
           <button type="button" name="button">Step 3</button>
       </form>
  </div>
```

--------------JavaScript-----------------------

```
var submit2 = document.querySelector("#form2 > form > button");

var sub = document.querySelector("#lol").value;

var customer = [];

submit2.addEventListener("click", function() {
     console.log("clicked");``
     console.log(sub);
})
```

------------------------Chrome Console --------------------

```
clicked
style.js:6 
sub
""
var sub = document.querySelector("#lol").value;
undefined
sub
"adsf"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that string is a primitive value and outside an object it will be passed as value instead of reference (See the explanation here https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)

When the browser loads the page, it will evaluate all the commands:

```
var submit2 = document.querySelector("#form2 > form > button");
 /* var submit2 = Dom reference object button */

var sub = document.querySelector("#lol").value;
/* sub = fixed empty string (the initial value of the input when the page loads) */

var customer = [];

submit2.addEventListener("click",
function() { 
    console.log("clicked");
    console.log(sub);
    /* when this function runs, sub.value evaluate the empty string of sub variable instead of get the new value property of #lol */
 }
)
```

Try to change to the reference of the object instead of the value:

```
    var submit2 = document.querySelector("#form2 > form > button");

    /* var sub = document.querySelector("#lol").value; */
    var sub = document.querySelector("#lol");
    /* sub = #lol DOM object reference */

    var customer = [];

    submit2.addEventListener("click",
function() { 
    console.log("clicked");
    /* console.log(sub); */
    console.log(sub.value);
    /* sub.value= new string of #lol object */
 }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marcelo. Sorry haven’t tried you answer yet but I just tried a few things and it worked when I put the variable (var sub) I side the function. Any idea why this is?..

Comment: @ADRai when the browser loads it checks the #lol value and put in the sub as string. When the click event raises, the function gets the empty value of the string instead of ask the current value property of #lol

Comment: But the Value is supposed to be a string since its text.. also even when I put it inside the function I still get a string which is what I wanted.. But why am I not getting the string in my original code..

Comment: @ADRai sorry, I edit my answer with the detail. Inside the function it work because you will get the static string after the #lol.value change.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer:

The javascript should wait, until the DOM is loaded entirely.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', start);

function start() {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
  // your code
}
```

Most people would use the 'load' event, but it is not as effective as the DOMContentLoaded Event.

Comment: Would you please accept the answer? Just click on the grayed check mark besides the answer.